# How to ignore one subplot in the legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have the following code:

```
warped_values = values_to_warp * factors
print(warped_values.shape)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.33, 2.5), dpi=300, constrained_layout=True)
fig.supxlabel("Sample points", fontsize=9)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,4,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,4,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,4,3, sharey=ax2)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(1,4,4, sharey=ax2)
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3]:
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=9)

ax1.plot(factors_vec, lw=0.85)
ax1.set_title("Curve with mean in (0.85, 1.15)", fontsize=9)
ax2.plot(values_to_warp, lw=0.85)
ax2.set_title("Motion data", fontsize=9)
ax3.plot((warped_values), lw=0.85)
ax3.set_title("Motion data warped", fontsize=9)

ax4.plot(values_to_warp - warped_values, lw=0.85)
ax4.set_title("Difference", fontsize=9)
# How to make the first entry invisible
fig.legend([""] + movement_columns, loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=3, fontsize=8)
```

producing these subplots:

[image]

The problem is, that the color for the first subplot is the color of the curve which I don't care about but I have to include it in the legend so that the color matches the labels of the other graphs. So, how would I ignore the color/entry of the first subplot in the legend (make it invisible) without leading to wrong colors for the other graphs?

Comment: Would `fig.legend(handles=ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()[0], labels=movement_columns, ....)` work for your case?

Comment: Through your comment, I found out that I just have to use an underscore instead of empty string which is automatically ignored

Comment: This is indeed mentioned in the matplotlib reference: [Specific artists can be excluded from the automatic legend element selection by using a label starting with an underscore, "_".](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html)